# Do northern areas in Pakistan have electricity and Internet?

Tags: internet, power, pakistan

Do these towns or valleys in Pakistan's northern areas have electricity and the Internet?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily find electricity, but of course you might get into trouble if you are too remote. So, better take a solar powered backpack, portable generator or other source of portable electricity.

Regarding mobile coverage, the best bet could be to pre-check the coverage zone on the mobile companies website. In Pakistan, some main telcos are Jazz, Ufone, telenor and zong. Also there are some satellite internet service provider companies like yasat. I am sure they cover not only the whole country but en entire region. So, you should not worry.

Good Luck!

Comment: Is `yasat` Pakistan based service?

Comment: No, Yahsat is a UAE based company but offers services in Pakistan as well.

Comment: But, do they operate from UAE or Pakistan?

Comment: It operates from UAE.

Comment: That means all of their machinery and control stations setup is in the UAE, not in Pakistan.

Comment: Yes, right. But a user should not care where the satellite and control stations are. Just like a GPS recevier that is in your mobile phone. You still get service round the globe regardless of whether the country has sats, ground stations etc. It is all about the coverage beams that covers the region.

Comment: @user366312 the satellites are not in tbe UAE, and that is what matters for connecting.

Answer (score 18):

Gilgit-Baltistan (formerly "Northern Areas") is a very large, thinly populated and extremely mountainous area, so conditions will vary widely.

The larger towns in the area have mobile phone coverage and thus mobile Internet access as well, see [this survey](https://www.pta.gov.pk/assets/media/qos_survey_all_cities_gb_07-12-2023.pdf) (2023 3Q, PDF) for oodles of detail.  As elsewhere in Pakistan, it is subject to being turned off with no notice at the whims of the local security agencies though.  Outside the populated valleys you can't expect to have any signal at all.

Electricity availability will be spotty at best, with frequent outages.  Some places will have backup power via generators or solar panels, others will not.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I've asked this question of Pakistani contacts an friends and got widely differing answers. || My interest is wrt the provision of low power solar and wind and maybe hydro power for developing country areas with minimal to no access to grid electricity. || I'm working on a project for refugee camps (initially for toilets) that will hopefully have wider applications. Lighting + mesh radio for maintenance purposes.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I would think that like in remote areas anywhere, especially in the mountains, it can vary a lot. Even in highly developed countries, getting grid power can be difficult or very expensive in some areas, as laying down cables, poles, etc. can be a challenge. Mobile Internet is often easier as you can cover large areas with a single tower, but as soon as there's a mountain between the tower and you're in the dark. Also weather events may have a influence on availability.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, check the other answer posted.